# How can I parse the table content from the website using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the tables present in sports website into list of dictionary to render into template, this is my first exposure to selenium, I tried to read selenium documentation and wrote this program

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211270.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print(len(soup.find_all("table")))
print(soup.find("table", {"class": "ratingstable"}))

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

I'm getting value as 0 and none, How can I modify to get all the values of table and store it in a list of dictionary?, If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, avoid using `time.sleep()`. It is against all best practices. Use an [**Explicit Wait**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

If you inspect the table, you can see that it is location inside the `<iframe>` tag with `name="testbat"`. So, you'll have to switch to that frame in order to get the contents of the table. It can be done like this:

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
browser.switch_to.frame('testbat')
```

After switching the frame, use the Explicit Wait as mentioned above.

Complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Add the following imports to your program
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211270.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

browser.switch_to.default_content()
browser.switch_to.frame('testbat')

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ratingstable')))
except TimeoutException:
    pass  # Handle the time out exception

html = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ratingstable').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

You can check whether you've got the table:

```
>>> print('S.P.D. Smith' in html)
True
```

Comment: How can I do for other tables in the  page they all contain same frame name? I tried to call with different attribute I got error saying No such frame

Comment: I think you should ask another question- how to select different frames with same name or something like that.